# OneDrive Search throws UnknownError when search contains "*"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

[**This is a copy paste from my original posted github issue**](http://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/161)

I'm working on a prototype application leveraging the Microsoft.Graph SDK. I noticed that if I run the following code on my "Live" / Personal OneDrive account it works just fine and returns the files I expect. However, if I run the same code against my OneDrive for Business, it throws an internal exception within Microsoft.Graph.Core. I suspect the reason is that my search Url contains a * as mentioned in the error, but why does it work when searching a Live account and break when searching a Work account?

Sample Code Snippet:

```
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
         new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
             (requestMessage) =>
             {
                 requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", ADALAuth.CurrentAccessToken);

                 return Task.FromResult(0);
             }));

            var drive = graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            var collection = graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Search("*.xyz").Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

**The error message returned is:**

```
Code: UnknownError
Message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*).

Inner error
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.DriveSearchRequest.<GetAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Profile\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\AzureWebApp\Default.aspx.cs:line 33
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Graph is routing your request to two different systems depending on your account type. Because of these, there are some subtle differences between the two systems.

Regardless, you shouldn't need the `*` as Search is already searching for the string you passed within other strings. In other words both `*.xyz` and `.xyz` get translated into `*.xyz*`. It will match this query in this way across several fields including filename, metadata, and file content.

Comment: So if I wanted to search and return only specific OneDrive files based off their file extension, I would have to search  `.xyz` and then post filter the response based off the file name ending?

Comment: Correct. I typically do a regex against the file name as part of the callback.